# Vim: how to change settings 'iminsert' and 'imsearch' in activated search mode immediately?

Tags: vim

I am trying to configure

```
nmap <C-F2> :set iminsert=1 imsearch=1<cr>
imap <C-F2> <C-O><C-F2>
```

in order to change vim language. It works well in command and insert modes.
But it does not work in a *search mode*.
Trying to implement it I wrote a function

```
function! Call_F2()
    set iminsert=1
    set imsearch=1
    return ""
endfunction
```

and mapped it with a

```
cmap <C-F2> <C-R>=Call_F2()<cr>
```

so I type / and press C-F2, but settings are not applied to the current search mode. Now I have to exit and re-enter search mode in order to see my changes applied.

The question is: how to change settings 'iminsert' and 'imsearch' in activated search mode *immediately*?

(I know I can use a shortcut C-^ and it works but I would like to map languages to their own shortcuts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for Joanis! I have improved hers/his solution:

```
nmap <C-F1> :set iminsert=0 imsearch=0<cr>
imap <C-F1> <C-O><C-F1>
cmap <C-F1> <END><SPACE><C-C><C-F1>/<UP><DEL>
"
nmap <C-F2> :set iminsert=1 imsearch=1<cr>
imap <C-F2> <C-O><C-F2>
cmap <C-F2> <END><SPACE><C-C><C-F2>/<UP><DEL>
```

the only side-effect I have noticed: the cursor always jumps to the end of search pattern.

Comment: Interesting solution, glad I could help develop it. I like the `<END><SPACE>...<DEL>` combination. Does it exit out for you when the pattern is not found? By the way, I can't figure out what `<C-C>` and `<C-O>` are (or even out to make `<C-F2>` work). What is your OS and vim version?

Comment: I just tested your solution fully: it works great, thanks! I now see what `<C-C>` and `<C-O>` do and they are much better choices than `<esc>` here, solving the limitations in my solution. As you say, the only side effect remaining is the jump to the end of the pattern.

Comment: Joanis: Vim 8.0.1453, Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to use `<C-F2>` like you (not sure why), but with `<F2>` instead this worked:

```
:cmap <F2> <esc>:set iminsert=1 imsearch=1<cr>/<up>
```

Limitation: with `<up>` at the end, it avoids clearing the current search line with I hit `<F2>`, but if the current search line is empty, it brings back the previous one and behaves badly if that search is for a string that doesn't exist.

I'm not sure how to detect if the current state of the search line was empty or not since I'm starting with `<esc>` which clears out of search mode to do the change.

It also has poor behaviour when the current search string is not found in the text, taking you out of search mode saying it cannot find that string.

All told, this solution is not great, but I want to post it anyway because it might serve as inspiration to develop a better one.

Comment: He-he, that is almost the solution! : )  Unfortunately I can not use <esc> or <C-[> because it does not work like Esc key, but I replaced it with <C-C>.